# Trying to create form field verification function in JavaScript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-hooks, event-handling

I am working on a survey page which has a family information section including total number of people in family, number of male, female and other genders.

so when the user submits the form the function check weather the sum of male female and other equals to the total no. of people in the family.

i created a function for this

```
export function verifyGenderCount( maleCount, femaleCount, otherCount, totalCount){
    if(maleCount+femaleCount+otherCount!==totalCount) alert("Gender Check Failed")
}
```

i am calling this inside handleClickNext function which is called every time user submits the form

```
const handleClickNext = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const {totalNoFemale, totalNoMale, otherGenderCount, totalNoOfPersons} = state.pageOne
        verifyGenderCount(totalNoMale, totalNoFemale, otherGenderCount, totalNoOfPersons)
```

notice that i am using context api along with usereducer since there are lot of questions and hence lot of states to manage in this survey.

Comment: does that going to help you ? seems you have lots of things in planning but not open up here. So you can take those as direction
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76539184/3157277 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76539066/3157277